# How can i go back to nvidia 295.33 driver?

Tags: 11.10, unity, nvidia

when i updated my nvidia driver to 295.40 Unity is not working any more i just get a black screen and nothing happens although Unity 2D and gnome classic are working fine so i think it's a problem with 3D acceleration...now how can i go back to 295.33 driver?

nvidia GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall current driver:
Go to aditional drivers and click uninstall
If you can not uninstall in this way, try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*
```

Then download the version of the driver you want from internet and double click to install it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Carlos,now it is working fine :)

Comment: you're welcome, than you for the feedback =)